# Python Regex not matching some of text

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code that matches *almost* everything I need it to.

```
import re
rx_sequence=re.compile(r"^(\d+:\s*\(\*\s*T.+)(?:\n?)((?:(?:\n|\r\n?).+)+)", re.MULTILINE)
text="""
2:(* Test #1 :: trj6tkjtkjty7ry7kyrukjkuy*)

  rtjtyjtryjtrkjyryukryukrkuy
test3test3test3test3test3test3+1;

3:(* Test3:: test3test3test3test3test3 *)

  Twwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwing test69test69';
tyjtdyjtdyjnrdtyntrdyntyntyn

69:(* Ttest69test69:test69test69 *)
  (*test69test69test69test69test69test69test69test69test69test6940: (* Finish Test case *)

    bTestDone := TRUE;

  40: (* Finish Test case *)

    bTestDone := TRUE;


  END_CASE;
  END_CASE;



(**********test10test10test10test10test10**************************)
10: (* Test10test10test10test10test10test10test10test10test10test10test10 *)

  test10[test10] := 'test10'; 
  (* petest10test10test10test10test10test10test10test10 *)  
  btest10test10e := TRUE;

  (* Run Sih';io0;'ioh;ui;oi;io;io;anageState OF

"""
for match in rx_sequence.finditer(text):
    title, sequence = match.groups()
    title = title.strip()
    print ("Title:\n",title)
    print ("\nSequence===========================================================================================:",sequence)
    print ("\n\n")
```

My regex isn't matching some of the body of case 69, and the last line of case 10.
I've been trying to come up with a regex that matches everything but no luck... I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/WG6UNV/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update the second part of your pattern to match the following lines that do not start with the pattern that matching at the beginning.

```
^(\d+:\s*\(\*\s*T.+)(?:\r?\n(?!^\d+:\s*\(\*\s*T).*)*
```

About the second part `(?:\r?\n(?!^\d+:\s*\(\*\s*T).*)*`

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n`
  - `(?!^\d+:\s*\(\*\s*T)` If what is on the right is not the pattern that indicated the beginning
  - `.*` Match any char 0+ times except a newline
- `)*` Close non capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qzFrjy/1/)

You can also wrap the second part in a capturing group if you want to have 2 groups in total.

[regex demo with 2 capturing groups](https://regex101.com/r/aOFzg9/1)

Comment: Yes, that captures all the groups, thank you. However if i were to add another case statement that begins with a different letter, why doesnt that get matched?
https://regex101.com/r/aOFzg9/2

Comment: @Real-Ragnar You have to add the charater class `[TF]` to the end as well https://regex101.com/r/2su7BY/1